# Most Pythonic way to iteratively build up a list?

Tags: python, list

I was trying to do something in Python that uses the following general procedure, and I want to know what the best way to approch this is.

First, an initialization step:

- Create an item M.
- Create a list L and add M to L.

Second, loop through the following:

- Create a new item by modifying the last item added to L.
- Add the new item to L.

As a simple example, say I want to create a list of lists where the nth list contains the numbers from 1 to n.  I could use the following (silly) procedure.

- Initially M is [1] and L=[[1]].
- Next, modify [1] by adding 2 to it to create the new item [1,2], then add [1,2] to L so L=[[1],[1,2]].
- Next, modify [1,2] by adding 3 to it to create the new item [1,2,3], then add [1,2,3] to L so L=[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]].
- Next, modify [1,2,3] by adding 4 to it to create the new item [1,2,3,4], then add [1,2,3,4] to L so L=[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]].
  etc.

I tried a few things, but most of them would modify not just the last item added but also items added to L in previous steps.  For the particular problem I was interested in, I did manage to find a solution that behaves properly (at least for small cases), but it seems inelegant, I’m not sure why it works when other things didn’t, and I’m not even confident that it would still behave as desired for large cases.  I’m also not confident that I could adapt my approach to similar problems.  It's not a case of me not understanding the problem, since I've coded the same thing in other programming languages without issues.

So I’m wondering how more experienced Python programmers would handle this general task.

(I’m omitting my own code in part because I’m new here and I haven’t figured out how to enter it on stackoverflow, but also because it's long-ish and I don’t want help with the particular problem, but rather with how to handle the more general procedure I described above.)

Comment: It'd be better if you posted the code. Also, write a concrete example showing sample input and expected output

Comment: +1 for a great first question. I'm a little unclear what you mean, though: "most of them would modify not just the last item added but also items added to L in previous steps." Is this not your desired behavior? If not -- why are you building this list? Can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez It's rather long, but I'll give it a shot once I figure out how.  I tried before, but it ended up a big mess, and got even messier when I tried to clean it up.

Comment: @PatrickCollins I wasn't sure if that would be clear.  In the example I gave, I would would want to have the lists in the first few steps to be
[[1]], 
[[1],[1,2]], 
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]],
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
but by the time I get to the 4th list, I might have something like
[[1],[1,3],[1,2,4],[1,2,3,4]]
for example.  So earlier items got modified further, after the only intended modification.
[

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When adding a list object `M` to another list, you are only adding a **reference**; continuing to manipulate the list `M` means you will see those changes reflected through the other reference(s) too:

```
>>> M = []
>>> resultlist = []
>>> resultlist.append(M)
>>> M is resultlist[0]
True
>>> M.append(1)
>>> resultlist[0]
[1]
>>> M
[1]
```

Note that `M is resultlist[0]` is True; it is the *same object*.

You'd add a *copy* of `M` instead:

```
resultlist.append(M[:])
```

The whole slice here (`[:]` means to slice from start to end) creates a new list with a shallow copy of the contents of `M`.

The generic way to build produce a series `L` from a continuously altered starting point `M` is to use a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions). Your simple *add the next number to `M`* series could be implemented as:

```
def growing_sequence():
    M = []
    counter = 0
    while True:
        M.append(counter)
        counter += 1
        yield M[:]
```

This will yield ever longer lists each time you iterate, *on demand*:

```
>>> gen = growing_sequence()
>>> next(gen)
[0]
>>> next(gen)
[0, 1]
>>> for i, lst in enumerate(gen):
...     print i, lst
...     if i == 2: break
...
0 [0, 1, 2]
1 [0, 1, 2, 3]
2 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: "When adding a list object M to another list, you are only adding a reference; continuing to manipulate the list M means you will see those changes reflected through the other reference(s) too." - yes.  This is the problem I was coming up against, but I wasn't sure of the best language to describe it.  So I guess I was asking how to get around this.  I think this answers my question.  Just to make sure I'm clear, does "gen" in your code correspond (roughly, at least) to L in my question?

Comment: @RandyE: instead of producing one big list, `gen` produces elements on demand (indefinitely); but yes, it is roughly your `L`, if you put the produced elements into a list.

Answer (score 3):

This will be based on [iterate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) from Haskell.

> `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`
>
> `iterate f x` returns an infinite list of repeated applications of `f` to `x`:
>
> `iterate f x == [x, f x, f (f x), ...]`

In Python:

```
def iterate(f, x):
    while True:
        yield x
        x = f(x)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> import itertools.islice
>>> def take(n, iterable):
...     return list(islice(iterable, n))

>>> take(4, iterate(lambda x: x + [len(x) + 1], [1]))
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

---

To produce a finite list, the type signature (again starting in Haskell just for clarity) could be `infiniteFinitely :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> [a]`.

If we were to use `list` in place of `Maybe` in Python:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def iterateFinitely(f, x):
    return map(lambda a: a[0], takewhile(len, iterate(lambda y: f(y[0]), [x])))
```

Example usage:

```
>>> list(iterateFinitely(lambda x: [x / 2] if x else [], 20))
[20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0]
```

---

Since ending with a falsy value is probably pretty common, you might also add a version of this function that does that.

```
def iterateUntilFalsy(f, x):
    return iterateFinitely(lambda y: [f(y)] if y else [], x)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> list(iterateUntilFalsy(lambda x: x / 2, 20))
[20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0]

>>> list(iterateUntilFalsy(lambda x: x[1:], [1,2,3,4]))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4], []]
```

Comment: The Haskell example does something similar what I want to do, except that in some cases, the list will be finite.  Does this matter?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
M=[1]
L=[M]

for e in range(5):
    li=L[-1][:]
    li.append(li[-1]+1)
    L.append(li)
```

Or more tersely:

```
for e in range(5):
    L.append(L[-1][:]+[L[-1][-1]+1])
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best way to do this is with a [generator](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/). That way, you don't have to deal with `list.append`, deep-copying lists or any of that nonsense.

```
def my_generator(max):
  for n in range(max+1):
    yield list(range(n+1))
```

Then, you just have to list-ify it:

```
>>> list(my_generator(5))
[[0], [0,1], [0,1,2], [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3,4], [0,1,2,3,4,5]]
```

This approach is also more flexible if you wanted to make it an infinite generator. Simply switch the `for` loop for a `while true`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
M = [1]
L = [M]  
for _ in xrange(3):
    L += [L[-1] + [L[-1][-1] + 1]]
```

After the above code is executed, `L` will contain `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`. Explanation:

- The first two lines simply seed the iteration with initial values
- The `for` line states how many loops we want to perform after the initial value has been set, `3` in this case. I'm using `_` as the iteration variable because we're not interested in its value, we just want to do a certain number of loops

Now for the interesting part; and remember that in Python a negative index in a list starts counting from the end, so an index of `-1` points to the last element.

- This: `L += …` updates the list, appending a new sublist at the end as many times as specified in the loop
- This: `[L[-1] + …]` creates a new sublist by taking the last sublist and adding a new element at the end
- And finally this: `[L[-1][-1] + 1]` obtains the previous last element in the last sublist, adds one to it and returns a single-element list to be concatenated at the end of the previous expression